# Understanding ListProperty backend behavior in GAE

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

I'm trying to understand how you're supposed to access items in a GAE db.ListProperty(db.Key).

#### Example:

A `Magazine` db.Model entity has a db.ListProperty(db.Key) that contains 10 `Article` entities. I want to get the Magazine object and display the Article names and dates. Do I make 10 queries for the actual article objects? Do I do a batch query? What if there's 50 articles? (Don't batch queries rely on the [IN operator, which is limited to 30 or fewer elements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8036420/jpa-and-many-to-many-relations-in-google-app-engine/8051462#8051462)?)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

So you are describing something like this:

```
class Magazine(db.Model):   
    ArticleList = db.ListProperty(db.Key)

class Article(db.Model):
    ArticleName = db.StringProperty()
    ArticleDate = db.DateProperty()
```

In this case the simplest way to grab the listed articles is to use the Model.get() method, which looks for a key list.

```
m = Magazine.get() #grab the first record

articles = Article.get(m.ArticleList) #get Articles using key list

for a in articles:
    name = a.ArticleName
    date = a.ArticleDate
    #do something with this data
```

Depending on how you plan on working with the data you may be better off adding a Magazine reference property to your Article entities instead.

Comment: Correct, except that it's not a query (line 3 in your second snippet) - it's just a datastore get, which is much faster.

Comment: Kevin- Ok thanks, so you're going the batch get route- but what about the second part of my question- isn't there a limit to how many records we can get in that manner?

Comment: @Yarin since its not a query but as Nick said a datastore get, there is not limit on how much you get get in a single call.

Comment: @KevinP you need to add to the code a check that if a is not None

Comment: @Yarin ditto on what Shay said about there being no limit on get results.  More practically speaking, key lists structures such as this one make it easy to paginate the data without having the overhead of a query offset.

Answer (score -2):

You need to read [Modeling Entity Relationships](http://www.google.co.il/url?sa=t&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CBYQFjAA&url=http://code.google.com/appengine/articles/modeling.html&ei=yJjKTsvSK4XWsga1uv2aBw&usg=AFQjCNEPa3yXZ4mPe7stemMzXYDOLwFMkg), especially the part about one to many.

Comment: I've read the docs, and that article is about ReferenceProperty- I'm asking about ListProperty. Moreover, you're missing the point of my question. I'm not trying to model a one-to-many relationship- That's an easy case that involves exactly 2 queries.

Comment: @Yarin What you have here IS a one-to-many relationship so you better off doing it the recommended way.

Comment: Yeah but my question is about understanding how ListProperty works, not about other ways to solve the example.