# Assign existing child entity for parent entity JPA- GAE

Tags: java, google-app-engine, jpa

I have 2 entity that have a relationship between them.

both of the entities has already created and inserted to the DB.
in some point the user has the ability to connect between them.
when im try doing it im getting:

> javax.persistence.PersistenceException: Detected attempt to establish
>   WannaMeetUser("654321") as the parent of WannaMeetUser("123456") but
>   the entity identified by WannaMeetUser("123456") has already been
>   persisted without a parent.  A parent cannot be established or changed
>   once an object has been persisted.

this is a transitive relation (user can have many friends from king of user):

the code is attached:

```
    @Entity 
    public class WannaMeetUser {

        @Id //signifies the primary key
        @Column(name = "ID", nullable = false)
        private Key id;

          @ManyToMany
          @Basic
          private List<WannaMeetUser> userFriends = new ArrayList<WannaMeetUser>();
}

public void addFriendToWannaMeetUser(@Named("userId") String userId,
            @Named("friendId") String friendId) {
        EntityManager mgr = getEntityManager();
        try
        {
            WannaMeetUser user = mgr.find(WannaMeetUser.class, WannaMeetServerUtils.getKeyFromString("WannaMeetUser", userId));
            WannaMeetUser friend = mgr.find(WannaMeetUser.class, WannaMeetServerUtils.getKeyFromString("WannaMeetUser", friendId));
            String coupleId = getcoupleId(userId.toString(), friendId.toString());
            if (friend == null || user == null) {
                throw new EntityNotFoundException("Object does not exist");
            }
            WannaMeetCouple couple=mgr.find(WannaMeetCouple.class, coupleId);
            if (couple == null) {
                couple = createCouple(userId.toString(), friendId.toString());
                couple.setId(coupleId);
                setUserJoined(couple, userId.toString(), friendId.toString(), true);
            }
         else {
            if (isFriendAllready(couple, userId.toString(), friendId.toString()))
                ;
            setUserJoined(couple, userId.toString(), friendId.toString(), false);
            doAddFriend(user, friend, 10, 12321321);
            mgr.persist(couple);
            mgr.persist(friend);
            mgr.persist(user);
        }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        finally{
            mgr.close();
        }

    }
```

my question is What is the best way to crate such a relationship ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The messages says user 1 has already been persisted without having any parent, but now we try 
to persist user 2 as a parent of user 1, but user 1 is known not to have a parent.

try to persist everything in one go using cascading instead.  You can declare a cascading relation like this:

```
@ManyToMany(cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
private List<User> userFriends;
```

And then persist everything in one go using cascading:

```
User user1 = new User();
User user2 = new User();

user1.getUserFriends().add(user2);

// this persists the whole tree in one go
entityManager.persist(user1);
```

Comment: Thanks for the comment, but the relationship is not known in the user creation, so your suggestion is not relevant for me.

Answer (score 0):

Parent-child entities should be used only for relationships that never change (e.g. a user and his photo). For dynamic relationships you have three options:

(A) Store references to other objects as a property (e.g. userFriends property in a User entity). If a relationship is unidirectional (e.g. User A likes User B), then you can update only one entity. For bidirectional relationships, you update both entities.

(B) Create a new entity type Relationship with two properties User A and User B. Create and delete these entities as necessary.

(C) When User A likes User B, create a new entity Relationship as a child entity of User A and use an id of User B as an id for this new Relationship entity.

The choice between these options depends on your data model and data access patterns.

Comment: Thanks for your help, regard option A, did you mean use a property without the  @ManyToMany annotation?

Comment: I am not familiar with how JPA maps to Datastore API. Take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8036420/jpa-and-many-to-many-relations-in-google-app-engine